# how to add icon to glass options menu item?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to create an options menu while in a specific immersion. How can I define an icon next to the menu item title?

I know when opening my app from the timeLine, my app icon is shown be default next to the relevant menu item, but now i want to do the same in a menu inside my app.

(I am using the Google Glass GDK.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this the same way that you would on Android, by specifying a resource in your menu item's `android:icon` attribute. For example,

```
<item android:id="@+id/foo" android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

would look for an icon named `res/drawable-*/my_icon.png`.

To match the recommended Glass UX/design guidelines, your icon should be white with a transparent background and 50 × 50 pixels.